# Image resizing working in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a function in my Angular 1.5 app that resizes a base64-encoded image if it's over a maximum size. This function works great in Chrome, but in Firefox it returns a empty string instead of anything base64-encoded.

[I've got it packaged up in an Angular app in Plunker here,](http://plnkr.co/edit/JqSBdjiLVJcfdhRZPeiM?p=preview) but here's the relevant function:

```
  // Image resizing
  $scope.resizeImage = function(base64Data, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = base64Data;
    height = img.height;
    width = img.width;

    if (width > maxWidth) {
      ratio = maxWidth / width; // get ratio for scaling image
      height = height * ratio; // Reset height to match scaled image
      width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if (height > maxHeight) {
      ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
      width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
      height = height * ratio; // Reset height to match scaled image
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // We set the dimensions at the wanted size.
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // We resize the image with the canvas method drawImage();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
    return dataURI;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to wait until the `<img>` is loaded:

```
img.onload = function() {
    // now your image is ready for use
};
```